# Swagger (Swashbuckle) hide header

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I use Swashbuckle to add Swagger documentation to my ASP.NET Web API project. How can I hide default header (with swagger logo) from documentation page without injecting CSS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you can do it olny by javascript right now.

In your **SwaggerConfig.cs** you can inject a .js file like this:

```
.EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
{                        
    c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "yournamespace.yourscript.js");
});
```

So in this script you can do whatever you want, like hide the header:

```
document.querySelector("#header").style.display = "none";
```

This [post](http://stevemichelotti.com/customize-authentication-header-in-swaggerui-using-swashbuckle/) shows how to customize the header putting two text boxes on it.

### Edit:

The approach suggested in @dimaKudr's answer is better. Inject a CSS style is enough to hide the menu (JS is not necessary).

Answer (score 16):

When I injected JS as suggested above, header was blinking at the page loading. It was shown for a second and then was disabled by script.
There is approach that works better for me. https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/476

You can inject CSS instead of JS:

```
#header {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: your approach is better for just hide the menu :)

Comment: In a newer version I needed to do `.topbar {
        display: none;
      }`

Comment: this is a trick but not a correct solution

Answer (score 0):

When I first ran into this I started injecting css/js but each time it was a struggle and kind of "hackish" to hide stuff with injected css. So after a while  I simply replaced the index file with a modified version of this [index.html](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/v5.2.1/Swashbuckle.Core/SwaggerUi/CustomAssets/index.html)
You can modify it as you like. Removing the div with the id=header will remove the header. Also this makes things such as replacing the logo etc much simpler. For the logo part you could set the logo src to en 64-bit encode as shown here [encode image](https://www.base64-image.de/). Also removing the linked favicon in the tab is as simple as removing the line. Also adding links to other pages etc is trivial. Injecting the index in you swaggerconfig as this

```
c.CustomAsset("index", thisAssembly, "Path.To.index.html");
```

Remember to set your index to embedded resource.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you hide by doing CSS or JS tricks, you cant actually hide it when you try it out.

CSS alternate is as folows;

```
.server {display: none;}
```